# How do you check whether an author list consists of only one or multiple authors in a custom driver in BibLaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm trying to hack myself together an APA 7 compliant driver for the movie bibliography type which should, for example look like the following:

> SurnameA, InitialA. & SurnameB, InitialB. (Executive Producers). (Year). *Title* [Format]. ProductionCompany.

I've so far written a driver using `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{movie}{...}` which does the above, with the exception of using the correct plural form of "Executive Producer" when more than one producer is present. It should then show "Executive Producers" instead.

How do I check whether a BibLaTeX list contains more than one item? I have skipped through the BibLaTeX documentation but I'm unable to comprehend the vast size of it whilst staying focused on the task at hand. Search engines have not helped either as most search strings I have entered supplied me with questions regarding the "end-user" use of BibLaTeX and not the package-development/customization use.

Further, I've tried string comparing
`\printnames[apaauthor][-1]{author}`
and
`\printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{author}`
which first of all sounds like a massive unnecessary hack and doesn't seem to work either, even though it is showing up equal when having just one author, and different when there are more.

I'm looking for something of this sort

```latex
\ifnumgreater{\listcount{author}}{1}{%
  \biblstring{execproducers}%
}{%
  \biblstring{execproducer}%
}
```

but I can't seem to find out how to access lists of fields outside of `\printnames[][]{}`.

Comment: I'm wondering whether you need to hack something at all. I'm assuming you already use `biblatex-apa`? The example file https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/master/bibtex/bib/biblatex-apa-test-references.bib contains many `@video` examples and picking one with executive producers like https://gist.github.com/moewew/e4f2896ff8d834b9e24796048636cfbe gives pretty much the output you describe.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like the way to go. APA7 didn't seem to have the String "execproducers" defined, so one has to set that first, but apart from that, it seems like it produces the output I desired.

Comment: I think `execproducers` is only translated for some languages, if your language is missing it and you have the translation, you may want to drop by https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course I had to find it shortly after posting the question. But here we go anyway. The documentation says as follows.

> For every list, there is also a counter by the same name which holds
> the total number of items in the corresponding list. For example, the
> author counter holds the total number of items in the author list.
> These counters are similar to `listtotal` except that they may also be
> used independently of list formatting directives.

See: BibLaTeX Documentation, v3.14 (2019-12-01), p. 181, http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf

This means by using `\value{author}` I could get the counter (and therefore the size) for the corresponding author list and I can use that compare it with *1*. This is the resulting code, which looks very similar to what I have had in mind earlier:

```
\ifnumgreater{\value{author}}{1}{%
  \ifbibstring{execproducers}{\biblstring{execproducers}}{Executive Producers}%
}{%
  \ifbibstring{execproducer}{\biblstring{execproducer}}{Executive Producer}%
}%
```

Edit: In my use case it turns out nothing had to be hacked in the first place. See moewe's comment on the question.

Comment: +1 for actually finding stuff in the manual ;-). The usual idiom in `biblatex.def` is the slightly longer [`\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumgreater{\value{author}}{1}} or test {\ifandothers{author}}}` (modulo line breaks)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2487-L2499) instead of `\ifnumgreater{\value{author}}{1}`. The difference being what happens when you say `author = {Emma Sigfridsson and others}`.